# Creating project from composer - Mercurial

Tags: php, version-control, mercurial, composer-php

I have a little problem with creating project from mercurial repository. Look like this:

Repo = `http://host/application-skeleton`

And now I want create (checkout) application skeleton and install all dependencies.

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://host/application-skeleton" application-skeleton test
```

What I must do besides this steps? I have create in application-skeleton composer.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found solution of my problem.

Composer use two different mechanism to load `packages.json` file.

**First way - local file**:

`packages.json`

```
{
    "package": {
        "name": "vendor/package-name",
        "version": "dev-default",
        "source": {
            "type": "hg",
            "url": "https://host/packages",
            "reference": "585637bc536f"
        }
    }
}
```

And call:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="./packages.json" vendor/package-name:dev-master test
```

**Second way - remote file (HTTP)**:

`http://host/packages/packages.json`

```
{
    "packages": {
        "vendor/package-name": {
            "dev-default": {
                "name": "vendor/package-name",
                "version": "dev-default",
                "source": {
                    "type": "hg",
                    "url": "https://host/vendor/package-name",
                    "reference": "585637bc536f"
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

And call:

```
php composer.phar create-project --repository-url="http://host/packages" vendor/package-name:dev-master test
```